# xlsx to csv: date format changed from DD.MM.YYYY to DD.MM.YY

Tags: excel, date, csv, format

I get despaired so I hope someone can help me.
I am exporting an Excel sheet (.xlsx) to a CSV file (.csv).
The table contains various types of information including some dates.
The dates are formatted as DD.MM.YYYY in the Excel sheet.
However when performing the export to a CSV file (File> Save as> CSV File) Excel changes the formatting of the dates to DD.MM.YY.
I need to import the data from the CSV file into R and the dates have to be in DD.MM.YYYY format.

Any idea how to force Excel keeping the formatting?
Many thanks and kind regards

Comment: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/mac/forum/macoffice2011-macexcel/data-changes-when-saving-from-xlsx-to-csv-file/c90ab942-6c18-46a2-8ca1-33db6b6198a3?db=5&auth=1

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14762834/saving-to-csv-in-excel-loses-regional-date-format  read deadcode answer

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer! Excel Version: 14.1.4 (Microsoft Excel for Mac 2011). Mac OS X Yosemite Version 10.10.5. CSV flavour: all 3 available Options (save as > Comma Separated Values, save as>Windows Comma Separated  and save as> MS-DOS Comma Separated) tried out but no one working the way I want...

Comment: Have you seen the links i post ?

Answer (score 0):

You can adapt this short macro to your needs:

```
Option Explicit
Sub CSV_Maker()
   Dim r As Range
   Dim sOut As String, k As Long, M As Long
   Dim N As Long, nFirstRow As Long, nLastRow As Long
   Dim MyFilePath As String, MyFileName As String
   Dim fs, a, mm As Long
   Dim separator As String

   ActiveSheet.UsedRange
   Set r = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
   nLastRow = r.Rows.Count + r.Row - 1
   nFirstRow = r.Row
   separator = ","

   MyFilePath = "C:\TestFolder\"
   MyFileName = "whatever"
   Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
   Set a = fs.CreateTextFile(MyFilePath & MyFileName & ".csv", True)

   For N = nFirstRow To nLastRow
       k = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Cells(N, 1).EntireRow)
       sOut = ""
       If k = 0 Then
           sOut = vbCrLf
       Else
           M = Cells(N, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
           For mm = 1 To M
               sOut = sOut & Cells(N, mm).Text & separator
           Next mm
           sOut = Left(sOut, Len(sOut) - 1)
       End If
       a.writeline (sOut)
   Next

   a.Close
End Sub
```