# A problem of the date format when an excel file is read as a csv file in python dataframe

Tags: python, excel, csv, dataframe, date-format

Original date format in excel file:
mm/dd/yyyy

Transferred date format in csv file:
mm/dd/yy

I would like to ask if there is any method to correctly read the date format from an excel file to a csv file.

If not, I would like further ask if there is any method to change the date format from mm/dd/yy back to mm/dd/yyyy via coding in python.

In addition, my question is different from the earlier ones posted here, as I am not allowed to make any changes on the excel file and the CSV file.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi, please take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14762834/saving-to-csv-in-excel-loses-regional-date-format

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Saving to CSV in Excel loses regional date format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14762834/saving-to-csv-in-excel-loses-regional-date-format)