# Is there a snowflake command to re-format a timestamp to ensure they are correctly displayed in a CSV export

Tags: csv, automation, timestamp, export, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

long time viewer, first time poster.

The issue I am struggling with relates to how my timestamp data appears in excel once I've run my code in snowflake and exported  it to CSV.  Unfortunately at the moment I am required to double click on these timestamp cells, once in exported into excel, for the true format (how it appears in results in snowflake) to appear.

There is a manual workaround to amend once the data is in excel, however I am automating this report for a client and therefore it must be presented correctly for them prior to the export.

As it stands (see below) the timestamp begins with YYYY-MM-DD and I have been asked to flip this firstly, to begin with DD. I thought that given I need to reformat the current timestamp, I may as well set it up correctly so the timestamp perhaps comes out as text, within the csv export? (from what I have read in other forums if you convert to text it is displayed in excel exactly how it appears in snowflake).

[image.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/coFyi.png)

As you can see, I continue to get the "Cant Parse" error. The  example timestamp given, is row 1 of the  'QuoteDate' variable.

The second part of the issue (or really the primary part of the issue) is how the timestamp completely changes format when exported (CSV) to excel. In the screen shot below I have double clicked the first 3 rows, leaving row 4 selected in order to show you all the error - which is the formula bar displays the correct format but the cell itself does not.

image.png

I hope this all makes sense and would love any assistance on how to amend this timestamp issue to run the code correctly, and present my client with a properly formatted timestamp within their extract.

Thank you :)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gaYX0.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For changing format

```
SELECT  to_char ( to_timestamp ('2019-01-02 09:36:22.507' , 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF') , 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS.FF')  AS TS
```

Timestamp/dates are stored as NUMBER in database, you need to convert in required format for correct display.

`to_timestamp` --> Converts an input expression into the corresponding timestamp. This expects the input to be in the format provided as second argument.

`to_char` --> Converts the input expression to a string format.

For preserving data format while converting from `csv` to `excel` check [Saving to CSV in Excel loses regional date format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14762834/saving-to-csv-in-excel-loses-regional-date-format)

Comment: Thank you for your help Digvijay,
the command above worked fine, however the issue lies within the export to CSV directly from snowflake.
I still have to double click into each cell to have the date appear properly in the cell (not just the formula bar).
I have created a macro to perform this step, now I need to find where to input this VBA - either into the snowflake script or into my Powershell script (JAMS) as that is where the reporting is automated and placed into a new xlsx sheet