# How to convert dates of a column from one format to another using pandas in python?

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime

I am trying to convert date from "16-Dec-21" format to "2021-12-01" format using Pandas in Python in a CSV file. Here's the table:

| Date | ID |
| --- | --- |
| 16-Dec-21 | 5665 |
| 11-Jan-22 | 5613 |
| 04-Feb-22 | 5680 |

Here's my code:

```
ds_com['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(ds_com['Date']).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

I've also tried

```
ds_com['Date'] = ds_com['Date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

But it also didn't work.

The new table should look like this:

| Date | ID |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-12-16 | 5665 |
| 2022-01-11 | 5613 |
| 2022-02-04 | 5680 |

The table has hundreds of rows.

The current output shows as this when I open the ds_com.csv file in Excel:

| Date | ID |
| --- | --- |
| 12/16/21 | 5665 |
| 1/11/22 | 5613 |
| 2/4/22 | 5680 |

The output shows correctly for

```
print(ds_com['Date'][1])
```

Thank you.

Comment: Your first line of code seems to work for me. Could you give another example or the output of `ds_com.info()`?

Comment: How are you determining that this isn't working? Are you saving the output?

Comment: Date cells show as this: 12/16/21

Comment: Is the "current output" from excel?

Comment: Yes, when I open the CSV file on excel, this is what it looks like. However, for print(ds_com['Date'][1]) the output displays correctly. How do I save it in this format in the document?

Comment: It is excel changing the format. You have 2 options, save the dates as YYYYMMDD soe xcel doesn't recognise them, or change to a custom data format in excel: yyyy-mm-dd

Let me know which one your after and I can post as an answer if that helps

Comment: More info here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14762834/saving-to-csv-in-excel-loses-regional-date-format

Comment: I want to go after yyyy-mm-dd format without having to manually change it on Excel. Thank you.

Comment: Maybe you should open the CSV in Notepad, not Excel. Side note: Excel is *terrible* with CSVs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this. It would cause excel to not auto format

```
ds_com['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(ds_com['Date']).dt.strftime('="%Y-%m-%d"')
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much!